# Python Selenium How to handle chrome store alert?

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

I'm trying to install chrome extention with selenium but when I clicked on "Add Extension", there was an alert like the picture below showed up, I'm not sure if it is an alert or not , but I saw error "no such alert". please help me
[image]

this is how I tried to handle this

```
alert = driver.switch_to.alert
alert.accept()
```

P/s : I also tried some other ways of handling alert but it wasn't worked so I don't think it is an alert. And I also don't want to use add_extension option

Comment: Are you sure this is an alert, not a dialog pop-up?

Comment: I'm don't know what it is , here is the link for chrome extenstion : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/phantom/bfnaelmomeimhlpmgjnjophhpkkoljpa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED**
Well, if you want to click on the alert message, try using this

```
 WebDriverWait(driver, wait_time).until(EC.alert_is_present())
 alert_msg = driver.switch_to.alert
 alert_msg.accept()
```

For some reason I was only able to click on the alert when I used the WebDriverWait to wait until the alert is present.

**Workaround**
If you want to add a extension you should use the options argument.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_extension('path/to/extension.crx')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('path/to/chromedriver.exe', options=options)
```

To download the CRX file use this extension: [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/crx-extractordownloader/ajkhmmldknmfjnmeedkbkkojgobmljda?hl=pt-BR)

**workaround number 2**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC, wait
from time import sleep

import pyautogui

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'.\drivers\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/phantom/bfnaelmomeimhlpmgjnjophhpkkoljpa')

elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div')))
elem.click()

sleep(3)
pyautogui.hotkey('tab','enter', interval=0.1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but for some reason I need to install it by clicking like the image, is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Mike, I updated the answer, hope this will help

Comment: It exactly what I tried to do , but it doesn't work, I don't know why , error : no alert

Comment: @Mike Are you sure you are in the right window when you try to click on the Alert? I had a similar problem in the past and I figured out that I had to switch to that window.

#this code moves you to the very new window
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])

Comment: I understand but there is only one Window and I tried to switch to alert to accept it but didn't work, and I can't find what's wrong :(

Comment: Man, this is weird. I created a project to do this and so far I was only able to install the extension using pyautogui. After the alert shows up I do pyautogui.hotkey('tab','enter', interval=0.1). It's a workaround, but I'm working on a real solution!

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I have done to solve this , but it is not good enough in some case, I hope you can find out the solution :( . Thank you