# Handle Add Extension Alert from webstore using only Selenium to make it work in headless

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

All the current solutions on Stack Overflow use pyautogui or some other method to click on the add extension alert. Or some will say to download and load the extension using ChromeOptions. Well, I do not want any of these. The reason is I need to make it work in headless mode and I can not download the extension for some reason.

Here is a link to similar question: [Python Selenium How to handle chrome store alert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69269098/python-selenium-how-to-handle-chrome-store-alert)

I have tried the steps in this post but they do not work. The code snippet to work with is:

```
import time
import pyautogui
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from undetected_chromedriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
options.add_argument("--disable-xss-auditor")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

driver = Chrome(service=service, chrome_options=options)
driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: function() {return false}})")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)

driver.get("https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chatgpt-chrome-extension/gabfffndnhbbjlgmbogpfaciajcbpkdn")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "webstore-test-button-label") and contains(text(), "Add")]')))
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "webstore-test-button-label") and contains(text(), "Add")]').click()

time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.hotkey('tab','enter', interval=0.1)
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context:

If the alert dialog is an OS-level window, Selenium, being a *browser* automation tool, cannot interact with it. Not to mention, Selenium works within the context of a browser, and in the headless mode, even that dialog will not appear.

---

> Different number of browser instances. I would be creating a lot of them, and it is not feasible to configure each profile manually.

The idea remain to have the `.crx` file of the extension already downloaded.

You can then create a new Chrome profile for each Selenium instance, install the extension in each profile, and then run your tests.
Once you have the `.crx` file, you can add the extension to Chrome using Selenium with the [`add_extension` option](https://python.hotexamples.com/examples/selenium.webdriver.chrome.options/Options/add_extension/python-options-add_extension-method-examples.html).

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=/path/to/your/new/profile")  # replace with the path to the new profile
options.add_extension('/path/to/your/extension.crx')  # replace with the path to the .crx file

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# continue with your automation tasks here

driver.quit()  # Remember to quit the driver when you're done with it
```

Note: The profile directory must exist and have write permissions. Selenium won't create a new directory for a profile.

This script will launch Chrome with a new profile located at the specified path and with the specified extension installed.

The advantage of this approach is that you can create as many profiles as you want by just providing a different profile directory path.

This approach should work in both GUI and headless modes. The only difference is that you need to add the `--headless` option when running in headless mode:

```py
options.add_argument("--headless")
```

---

> I have said that I do not want to load the extension, I want to do it by clicking the Add extension pop up. I have come up with athing that passing key strokes to the headless browser using it's handler. I have done something similar in c++ but do not know how to do it in python, at OS level automation using winapis.

Selenium would not be able to replicate that at the (headless) browser level, hence this answer:

- download the extension
- add the extension in the profile used by Selenium

In your specific use case where you are programmatically adding an extension using a `.crx` file, you do not need to navigate to the Chrome Web Store page for the extension.
The `driver.get()` method is used to navigate to a specific URL, and since you are adding the extension directly, you do not need to visit the extension's page on the Chrome Web Store.

Comment: I want to automate the installation, because I have to use different browser instances

Comment: @farhanjatt Do you mean different version of the same extension, on for different browser instance? Then, as a workaround, why not different profiles, each one with the right version of the extension already downloaded, for you to use with the right browser instance?

Comment: Different number of browser instances. I would be creating lot of them and it is not feasable to configure each profile manually

Comment: @farhanjatt OK, I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I have said that I do not want to load the extension, I want to do it by clicking the Add extension pop up. I have come up with athing that passing key strokes to the headless browser using it's handler. I have done something similar in c++ but do not know how to do it in python

Comment: @farhanjatt "I have done something similar in c++": did you do it in C++ with Selenium? Because the all point of this answer is to explain that interacting with an OS-level window alert dialog using Selenium, a *browser* automation tool. Not to mention, Selenium works within the context of a browser, and in the headless mode, even that dialog will not appear.

Comment: No, I did that at OS level automation using winapis

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254593/discussion-between-vonc-and-farhan-jatt).